# String trim. to remove last characters from the end

Tags: c#, string, trim

have a bit of a a problem.
I have these strings

```
[14]: "Care_CAR_3RD_DAY_201309177438417"
[15]: "Care_201309177438417"
[16]: "New_Care_201309177438417"
[17]: "SMS_New_Care_20130917"
```

This is a list of files that gets generated daily and I would like to remove the numbers at the end so as to be able to compare each file name to a record in the db to perform a specific action. Also the number at the end is not always the same size.
The result would be

```
[14]: "Care_CAR_3RD_DAY"
[15]: "Care"
[16]: "New_Care"
[17]: "SMS_New_Care"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though jyparask answer is valid but it would fail if input is something like this **Care_CAR_3RD_DAY201309177438417**.

The safe approach would be

```
string test = "Care_CAR_3RD_DAY_201309177438417";
test = test.TrimEnd(new char[]{'_','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'});

//output Care_CAR_3RD_DAY
test = "Care_CAR_3RD_DAY201309177438417";
test = test.TrimEnd(new char[]{'_','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'});

//output Care_CAR_3RD_DAY
```

Comment: The same as what `String.Remove` with a single parameters internally does, but less redable imho.

Comment: As i mentioned above "Care_CAR_3RD_DAY20130917_7438417" will produce "Care_CAR_3RD_DAY" which would be wrong as the asker only needs to trim numbers after the last dash. But still the point in my opinion is to get correct results in specific input and not in `every` case, or else the framework would have some function for it.

Answer (score 7):

```
string test = "Care_CAR_3RD_DAY_201309177438417";
test = test.Remove(test.LastIndexOf('_'));
```

If you are not sure if there is a '_' then you can check for it:

```
test = test.IndexOf('_') > -1 ? test.Remove(test.LastIndexOf('_')) : test;
```

Comment: In real code you'd want to check the return value of `LastIndexOf()` to ensure that it isn't -1

Comment: Your approach would fail if input is something like Care_CAR_3RD_DAY201309177438417.

Comment: @NoOne Based on the input from the asker this is correct. Take for instance "Care_CAR_3RD_DAY20130917_7438417", your solution will fail here too. Is there a point of finding the solution to every case when we have very specific rules? The format of the input strings end in "_number" so this is my test case. All others are wrong input in my opinion.

Comment: @jyparask it won't fail. Try it. And strings end in "_number" is not defined by user. You have assumed it. Thirdly, being a engineer you need to check all angles. Fourthly, if removing unserscores is not a requirement then just removing it from the char array would do it.

Comment: @NoOne It does fail as the output is "Care_CAR_3RD_DAY" which means it trimed more numbers than it should. The correct result would be "Care_CAR_3RD_DAY20130917".

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regex.

```
  var newString = Regex.Replace(inputString, @"\d*", string.empty);


Input: Care_CAR_3RD_DAY_201309177438417
Result: Care_CAR_3RD_DAY_
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I managed to solve it

fname.Replace(fname.Split('*').Last(),"").TrimEnd('*')